# How to resolve seemingly natural dependency

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-management

I am writing a symbolic math library. I have an interface

```
interface IDifferentiable {
    string Name;
    Expression<IDifferentiable> Differentiate(Variable v);
}
```

And concrete class

```
class Variable : IDifferentiable {

}
```

Both these structures depend on each other and there is a third generic class that is basically a simple tree to represent an expression that both these classes depend on.

My fundamental question is: Is this circular dependency a bad thing? I have been told that it should never happen and is considered a 'design smell'. There seems to be no way to separate them into distinct components. Fundamentally it makes sense to have them both depend on each other because the `Differentiate` method requires specifically a `Variable` and will not work with a different `IDifferentiable`. Similarly, the `Variable` class needs to implement `IDifferentiable` otherwise I will have to rethink the entire structure of my program and this is one of the components I was most satisfied with.

I have really only considered one solution: to change the interface method to take an `IDifferentiable` instead of a `Variable`. The differentiation method currently does not depend on any component of `Variable` that does not exist in `IDifferentiable` so this would not cause immediate problems. I know it is also a common practice for an interface to reference itself. However I am uncomfortable doing this because it makes sense for `Differentiate` to require a `Variable` specifically. Is this a valid problem and is there a solution that does not require redesigning the entire project. I am still in the very early stages which is why I am so worried about this, as I intend to extend functionality in the future.

Comment: Instead of concrete Variable inside Differentiate method, use also IDifferentiable. So u will have  Expression<IDifferentiable> Differentiate(IDifferentiable v). Now u keep the method generic without concrete variable defined. U can always cast it to Variable if u need it in an implementation....because Variable is IDifferentiable.

Comment: It's difficult to say for certain, since you leave out parts of your code, but in general, these sorts of problems can be modelled as abstract syntax trees without resorting to circular dependencies. Try doing the exercise in F# without using the `and` keyword. You may be able to find lots of examples of such exercises in F# or other functional languages. Despite the current *oop* tag this sounds like a classic FP exercise.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* do things this way it's generally confusing to have any kind of circularity in your dependencies.

In this case you can resolve the circularity by adding an intermediate `IVariable` interface that `Variable` implements, and reference that in your `Differentiate` method definition:

```
interface IVariable
{
    string Name { get; }
    object Value { get; }
}

interface IDifferentiable
{
    string Name { get; }
    Expression<IDifferentiable> Differentiate(IVariable variable);
}

class Variable : IVariable, IDifferentiable
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public object Value { get; }

    public Variable(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public IDifferentiable Differentiate(IVariable other)
    {
        // compute differentiation (whatever that is) here.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This doesn't introduce any loops in your dependency tree, but I'll admit it is a little strange to pull out an interface just for this. If you're concerned about the dependency loop then this is one way to address it.

One advantage it has though is that you can have different classes that satisfy the interface spec, such as a type that implements `IVariable` but not `IDifferentiable` or vice versa.